# Add comments to a Python script and make it a bilingual Python/C++ “program”

Tags: code-golf, python, polyglot, programming-puzzle, c++

Given the following Python 3 script:

```
def greet():
    print("Hello, world!")

greet()
```

***Prepend*** some lines to this text file so that it can be both executed as a Python program as well as compiled and run as a C++ program producing the same output **Hello, world!** (including the newline at the end):

```
$ python3 bilingual.py.cpp
Hello, world!
$ g++ bilingual.py.cpp && ./a.out
Hello, world!
```

The solution will be scored by the count of non-whitespace characters of the entire program, including the Python script:

```
sed 's/\s//g' bilingual.py.cpp|wc -c
```

Comment: In the title you say add comments,  however in the body you say you only have to prepend some lines.  Which is it?

Comment: @WheatWizard The title is a hint. If you can solve this by prepending arbitrary lines (non-comments) I will be puzzled.

Comment: This is a very nice question. My only remark would be to just stick to the byte count for scoring in the future. It's simpler to check for those on different systems.

Comment: @Linus I admit that selecting the score in a non standard way was a mistake. Will not repeat it in the future.

Comment: Just a note: the provided sed command count the newlines, that are whitespace characters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Score 116

Prepend:

```
#include<cstdio>
#define print(A)main(){puts(A);}
#define greet()
#define \
```

The preprocessor backslash `\` pulls the nasty `:` containing line into an unused macro. Try it [here](http://ideone.com/eFDNtU).

Thanks to [edc65's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98660/46756) for the note about implicit int in C++4.
Thanks to [PieCot's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98664/46756) for suggesting `<cstdio>` over `<stdio.h>`.
Thanks to [Leon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61709/leon) for suggest I remove the `X` in the original `#define X\`.

Comment: I don't have sed, if someone could verify my score I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Removing all whitespace, my count (by hand) is 110 (but I was wrong... it's 111)

Comment: @Linus Why do you need the X in `#define X\\`?

Comment: @Leon good catch!

Comment: For anyone wondering what C++4 is: In this case it is short for *"The C++ that gcc 4.3.2 accepts"*.

Answer (score 11):

## Score 119

(Thx @Linus for the byte count)

(1 byte saved thx @Conor O'Brien)
(1 byte saved thx @PieCot)

<s>Counting bytes again by hand, I found 113. Maybe it's right this time.</s> No it's not

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#define def main(){0?
#define print(x) puts(x);}
#define greet()
```

Notes: stdio and puts are still alive and kicking in C++. The missing int type is valid in C++ 4. [Test](http://ideone.com/DA8nVq)

Comment: The score must be computed against the full program (including the python code).

Comment: Since the ternary conditional can have an empty second portion, you can remove the trailing `0` on line 2. [Test.](http://ideone.com/oYY6m3)

Comment: OK I don't see why, as the python code will be the same for every answer, but you are the boss. I did the count by hand, not having sed, I hope it's right

Comment: @ConorO'Brien it really can! I did not know! Thx

Comment: You can use <cstdio> rather than <stdio.h>

Comment: So I managed to get an [online terminal](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php) working and `sed 's/\s//g'` leaves the newlines. This ends up being 119 characters.

Comment: Well if, `sed` leaves the newlines, that it's not `count of non-whitespace characters`, as newlines (like tabs, carriage return and the like) are whitespace characters. I keep my count

Comment: @Linus I changed my mind, and I'll use your count, even if it does not feel right. We need consistency

Answer (score 7):

## Score <s>131 130</s> 134

The lines to be prepended are:

```cpp
#import <iostream>
#define def int main(){0?
#define greet()
#define print(A) 0;std::cout<<A"\n";}
```

And the resulting code:

```cpp
#import <iostream>
#define def int main(){0?
#define greet()
#define print(A) 0;std::cout<<A"\n";}
def greet():
    print("Hello, world!")

greet()
```

### Testing

```
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming\golf
λ type bilingual.py.cpp

#import <iostream>
#define def int main(){0?
#define greet()
#define print(A) 0;std::cout<<A"\n";}
def greet():
    print("Hello, world!")

greet()
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming\golf
λ sed 's/\s//g' bilingual.py.cpp|wc -c
134

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming\golf
λ g++ bilingual.py.cpp 2>nul && a
Hello, world!

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming\golf
λ python bilingual.py.cpp
Hello, world!

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming\golf
λ
```

Comment: The output of the C++ version is not identical to the python version - it misses a newline. Added that clarification to the question.

Comment: @Leon This is now fixed.

Comment: `#import` is not valid C++

Comment: @Leon It may be deprecated but it is valid. It works in `g++`.

Comment: Clever handling of `:`

Comment: It is a deprecated gcc extension. g++ was used just as an example. The problem formulation requires a C++ program. And there is no sense arguing about that 1 char, since everyone will have to have that `#include` in their solution.

Comment: @Leon Our site rules say that if it works in one environment, it's a valid submission.

Comment: @Leon not everyone will have *that* `#include`, even if probably everyone will have some `#include`

Comment: @edc65 By *that* `#include` I meant the **include** as opposed to **import**.

Answer (score 6):

### Score <s>110</s> 104

Improving upon [Linus' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98665/61709):

```
#include <cstdio>
#define print main(){puts
#define greet() ;}//\
def greet():
    print("Hello, world!")

greet()
```

[Test as C++](http://ideone.com/I40MWe)

[Test as Python](http://ideone.com/toBTSk)

Comment: I have get 109...

Comment: @Linus I have a new line at the last line

Answer (score 5):

### Score 136

Only for the records:

```
#include <cstdio>
#define def class a{public
#define greet()
#define print(a) };int main(){puts(a);}
```

Another (less efficient) way to handle the colon.

Comment: But `cstdio` should be noted.

Comment: I think the score for this ends up being 136. You don't count the spaces.

Comment: @Linus: Thanks! I think you are right. If I use this command:

`tr -d '[:space:] ' < bilingual.py.cpp | wc -c` 

I get 128, while this one:

`tr -d '[:blank:] ' < bilingual.py.cpp | wc -c` 

provides 136